# Shopify Custom Discount Code

Tags: shopify

I am new to shopify and I have noticed that resources/docs route users to create an app for any new functionality.

I want to modify shopify's functionality in one case.  if a specific discount code is typed I would allow for a percent off.  However, I want to set the tax = 0.  Do I need an app for that?  Am i missing something, is an app the only way to modify functionality for a specific store?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot confuse the two concepts. If a person uses a discount code, it affects the subtotal in the checkout, and at that point taxes are assessed or not on the subtotal, depending on the tax setup in Shopify. You cannot switch the assessment of taxes on or off based on the use or presence of a discount code. No App can do that.

Comment: I believe I can achieve his functionality if I set up specific users as non-tax users.

Comment: The customer API http://docs.shopify.com/api/customer indicates no connection between customers and taxes.

Comment: can you modify any dollar amount with the api.  Can I change the shipping price?